# Local minimization of a function over a line

Tags: optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Suppose $x^*$ is a local minimizer of $f$ along every line that passes through $x^*$. This means that the function $$g(\alpha) = f(x^* + \alpha d)$$ is being minimized for $\alpha = 0$ for any direction $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It is easy to show that this implies $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$.

The question is:

> Is $x^*$ a local minimizer of $f$?

The answer is, it can be a local minimizer, maximizer, or a saddle point. I really don't get the reason. We are given that, for sufficiently small $\alpha>0$, $f(x^*) \leq f(x^* + \alpha d), \forall d \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Doesn't this also imply that $x^*$ is a local minimizer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

Consider $n=2$, $f(x,y)=(y+x^2)(y+2x^2)$ where  and consider $(x^*, y^*)=(0,0)$.

\begin{align}g_d(\alpha)&=f(\alpha d_1, \alpha d_2)\\&= (\alpha d_2 + (\alpha d_1)^2)(\alpha d_2 + 2(\alpha d_1)^2)\\
&= \alpha^2(d_2+\alpha d_1^2)(d_2+2\alpha d_1^2)\\
&= \alpha^2(2d_1^4\alpha^2 + 3d_2d_1^2\alpha+d_2^2) \end{align}

We know that $g_d(0)=0$, let's study what happens when $\alpha \ne 0$.

If $d_2=0$, then we have $g_d(\alpha ) \ge 0$.

If $d_2 \ne 0$, note that $2d_1^4\alpha^2 + 3d_2d_1^2\alpha + d_2^2>0$ when $\alpha$ is small but non-zero, hence $g_d(\alpha)\ge 0$ near the zero neighborhood.

Hence $(0,0)$ is a local minimizer of $f$ along every line.

However,

$$f\left(x, -\frac32x^2\right) = \left(-\frac32x^2+x^2\right) \left(-\frac32x^2+2x^2\right)=-\frac14x^4\le 0$$

In particular, we can let $x$ be arbitarily small and non-zero.

Hence $(0,0)$ is not a local minimum.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also have a counter-example: $f(x_1, x_2) = (x_2 - x_1)^2(x_2 - 2x_1^2)$. However, I don't get the intuition. Can you please help me with the intuition?

Comment: I think counterexamples illustrate that even though we restrict it to a line, a point is a minimum along the restricton. However, if we draw a neighborhood, and draw a certain small curve, we can find a smaller value.

Comment: That's very hard to imagine... I always think like if $x^*$ is the minimum over each line, then it is local minimum, because any point in the very-small-ball around $x^*$ also is on a line from $x^*$.

Comment: not sure if a [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/edtgj6dgfk) link would help.

Comment: Thank you  very much!

Comment: I think part of the intuition is that, in your statement about "sufficiently small $\alpha > 0$, the "sufficiently small" part is different for each direction. So for any given $\alpha$, there's a direction in which it is not small enough to prevent a decrease in $f$.

Comment: @prubin This actually concluded my question. Thanks for that. It is very hard to imagine visually :)